# NodeJS Buffer Size Logic: why 8KB as a default and not just the data size?

Tags: node.js, binary-data

If you read a file smaller than 8KB in size [NodeJS allocates 8 KB for it](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#class-property-bufferpoolsize).

This isn't intuitive or expected, we are getting "more" bytes than we put. But it isn't a bug either at least in the sense that it is documented.

**Minimal NodeJS Example**

```js
const { Buffer } = require("node:buffer");

// Create a buffer smaller than `Buffer.poolSize`.
const nodeBuffer = Buffer.from(new Uint8Array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]));

// size is 8KB, not 5 bytes.
console.log(nodeBuffer.buffer);
```

**Question**

- Why would 8KB buffer size be preferred over what we expect to have (the size of the data in the file.) ?

Files over 8KB would have an allocated space that matches the number of bytes in the file.

**Other Details**

I'm aware that we can use the offsets for reading:

```js
// 1 KB
const buffer = fs.readFileSync(fileName, buffer.byteOffset, buffer.byteLength)
```

but the question isn't this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is in the name of the property you linked, `poolSize`.

[Elsewhere on the same page](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferallocunsafesize):

> The `Buffer` module pre-allocates an internal Buffer instance of size `Buffer.poolSize` that is used as a pool for the fast allocation of new Buffer instances created using `Buffer.allocUnsafe()`, `Buffer.from(array)`, and `Buffer.concat()` only when size is less than `Buffer.poolSize >>> 1` (floor of `Buffer.poolSize` divided by two).

In other words, it's for performance reasons, since allocating and deallocating memory can be slow; instead, there's a pool of memory the module dips into for suitably small allocations. If you want a smaller buffer, it'd probably still be less efficient to allocate it from out of the pool than to have a buffer that's a bit bigger than what you need.

(At the time of writing) you can use the [`buf.buffer` and `buf.byteOffset` properties](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufbuffer) to see that two small allocations were indeed done off the same `ArrayBuffer`:

```
> const { Buffer } = require("node:buffer");
> a = Buffer.from([1,2,3,4])
<Buffer 01 02 03 04>
> a.buffer
ArrayBuffer {
  [Uint8Contents]: <2f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ...>,
  byteLength: 8192
}
> b = Buffer.from([5,6,7,8])
<Buffer 05 06 07 08>

> b.buffer
ArrayBuffer {
  [Uint8Contents]: <2f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 04 00 00 00 00 05 06 07 08 00 ...>,
  byteLength: 8192
}
> a.byteOffset
8
> b.byteOffset
16
>
```

Comment: That's interesting. So reading a file < 8KB is actually putting the content in an already existing buffer. I wonder if they could overwrite data by mistake, but I guess they fill it up sequentially and keep an offset.

Comment: [You're free to look for bugs in the implementation.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/639c09600418c42ff91979d60392d02c269c4dab/lib/buffer.js#L426-L458)